# Adding Category in foreach with knockout js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I got an array full of documents. This documents have some categories and they are sorted by the category. For each category I would like to have a title like:
- Sport
--- SportDocument 1
--- SportDocument 2
--- SportDocument 3
- Tournaments
--- TournamentDocument 1
--- TournamentDocument 2
--- TournamentDocument 3

So the categories "Sport" and "Tournaments" are titels.

My problem is I don't know how I can create a new Div with this Title to have a list.

My current code

```js
var DocumentRow = function (documentLine) {
    var self = this;
    // getting name and ID of the document
    self.Name = ko.observable(documentLine.Name);
    self.DocumentId = ko.observable(documentLine.DocumentId);

    // creating downloadLink
    self.DocumentLink = ko.computed(function () {
        return "someUrlPath/read/import/" + self.DocumentId();
    });
}




GetCustomerDocuments(data.SomeID)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        // Reset Documents from Previous View
                        self.documentLines([]);
  
                        // Only mapping when it has some data
                        if (data !== null && data !== undefined && data.length > 0) {
                            // loop trought the arry
                            self.documentLines(data.map(function (doc) {
                                return new DocumentRow(doc);
                            }));
                        }
                    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: documentLines">
  <div class="importDocument">
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: DocumentLink}, target:'_blank'">
      <span data-bind="target:'_blank'">
        <img src="../images/pdf.png" title="Document" />
      </span>
      <span data-bind="text: Name, target:'_blank'" title="Document"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean solution that produces easy-to-read data-binds is to create a `ko.computed` that adds a grouping layer to you data. You'd create this structure:

- documentLines

  - documentGroup

    1. documentRow
    2. documentRow
    3. ...
  - documentGroup

    4. ...

The computed uses your `documentLines` array as a starting point, makes a group for each unique `Category` it encounters, and pushes the documents that match this category to the group.

You haven't shown the actual `Category` property, so I'll just assume it's a string property inside each `documentRow`.

The code below shows you an example of how a grouped computed would work. Check out the comments for an explanation of what's happening. Grouping objects by a property is a common thing to do and there should be many other examples on stackoverflow that show you how you can go about it. This is more about how knockout works:

```js
var VM = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  // This is our data source
  self.documentRows = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  // This injects a group layer and will be used in our foreach:
  self.docGroups = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    // This creates a subscription that makes sure the object is updated
    // every time the documentRows are updated
    var rows = self.documentRows();
    
    // Grouping logic: 
    //  create an object of: { "CategoryName": [ /* documentRows*/ ] }
    var categoryMap = rows.reduce(function(map, row) {
      var category = row.Category;
      map[category] = map[category] || [];
      map[category].push(row);
      return map;
    }, {});
    
    // Transform to object and sort by name
    return Object.keys(categoryMap)
      .map(function(k) {
        return { name: k, rows: categoryMap[k] }
      })
      .sort(function(c1, c2) {
        return c1.name.localeCompare(c2.name);
      });
  });
}

var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.documentRows.push({Category: "Cat1", Text: "The First Document"});
vm.documentRows.push({Category: "Cat2", Text: "The Second Document"});
vm.documentRows.push({Category: "Cat2", Text: "The Second 2nd Document"});
vm.documentRows.push({Category: "Another category", Text: "The Third Document"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>Categories:</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: docGroups">
  <li>
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: rows">
      <li data-bind="text: Text"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Other approaches:**

If you don't want a nested structure, you can also make a flat list that has two types of objects: documents and groups. You'll have to use an `if` or `template` binding to determine how you want it to render.

If you're sure your data is sorted by your grouping property, you *could* create the logic of whether you need a category label inside your view by checking for `$parent.documentLines()[$index() - 1].Category === $data.Category`, but I'd strongly advice against this...